# How to create a typescript watcher for phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I tried:

```
  watchers: [
    esbuild: {Esbuild, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--sourcemap=inline --watch)]},
    tailwind: {Tailwind, :install_and_run, [:default, ~w(--watch)]},
    tsc: ["--noEmit --watch"]
  ]
```

But that doesn't appear to work. I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I got it

```
  watchers: [
    ...
    typescript: [
      ".assets/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
      "--noEmit",
      "--watch"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: are the other two watchers included as well? meaning you have esbuild, tailwind, and typescript?

Comment: That did not work for me. See my answer in your other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/78068160/5486165