# phoenix watcher results in executable does not exist

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have this inside of `watchers`

```
    typescript: [
      "./assets/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
      "--noEmit",
      "--watch",
      "-p",
      "assets"
    ]
```

But it results in `[error] Could not start watcher "typescript" from "/Users/.../Packages/tester", executable does not exist`

But `./assets/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --watch --noEmit -p assets` works fine.

I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    tsc: [
      "--noEmit",
      "--watch",
      "-p",
      "../../../",
      cd: "assets/node_modules/typescript/bin/"
    ]
```

Is the solution I think. I do wonder if there's a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did not work for me. Rather:

```
    node: [
      "assets/node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
      ...,
      "--project",
      "./assets/"
    ]
```